# How to configure DDEV on AWS Linux for multiple users on same machine

Tags: ddev

We've been working on separate machines, now I'm setting up a single Linux machine on AWS that all of us will RDP into, to do our work.

On our separate machines, we've named our projects the same, so that we use a single configuration, and it doesn't get confusing.

Now, if we do that on AWS, we will be overwriting each others Docker containers.

Where, what, and how should I configure? So that DDEV knows to build containers for each Linux user?

I googled and did not find clear answers.

Comment: Is it essential that the directories be the same name on each system?  Because the simple solution would be just add a prefix or suffix to the name so it knows which user so that each directory is unique.  Now if the project REQUIRES them to be the same, then this won't work obviously.  D:\WORK could be D:\WORK_TIM AND D:\WORK_BOB or something like that?

Comment: The current answer gives good advice about taking a single EC2 instance each. However, given this is for development, I wonder if you will bump into latency problems when doing development in this remote fashion. Could you edit your post to explain why you can't just do this work on your individual dev machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDEV is intended for local development, where each developer has their own environment.

That means if you want to use AWS, you should each have a separate EC2 instance, and you'll be fine.

I don't think you'll be happy with using a single shared EC2 instance for many, many reasons, and I don't think DDEV is the proper solution if you're committed to doing that. And the same goes for other Docker-based solutions, for the very reasons you're discovering.

Some options you may want to consider if you're committed to cloud-based work are:

- Using separate EC2 instances, one per developer. I've done this for years and it's worked fine. My [first post about doing it](https://randyfay.com/content/my-new-development-computer-amazon-ec2-instance) goes back to 2009.
- Use [gitpod](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/ddev-installation/#gitpod) - it works great.
- Use [GitHub Codespaces](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/install/ddev-installation/#github-codespaces), also works great.